# Rasberry Pi - Tesseract error

Tags: raspberry-pi, ocr, tesseract, raspbian

I downloaded tesseract with reference to this website

(https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/tesseract-ocr-installation-and-usage-on-ubuntu-16-04/)

and executed tesseract but it didn't work. It showed this error message:

```
 Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to
 the parent directory of your tessdata directory
```

How can I solve this problem?

I already downloaded trained language data using this command:

`sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-eng`

[image]

Comment: Any feedback for my answer below? By the way, please read this ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

It looks the `TESSDATA_PREFIX` environment variable hasn't been set in your `Raspbian`. Your have to set it with the absolute path to `~/tessdata`. Below is a sample command.

```
export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/path/to/tesseract/tessdata/
```

Then make sure the `eng.traineddata`, trained English language data, saved in the directory of `TESSDATA_PREFIX`.  You can use the `find` command to search the trained data file if you didn't know where was it saved to.

```
find / -name eng.traineddata
```